# Domain cookie (_ga) from upper-level domain

Tags: google-analytics, subdomain, cookie

I have deleted Google analytics account, Google site Kit plugin and Google .html verification file from the server about 30 min ago. Yet, I see a _ga cookie still being set. For example, we can take [this page](https://liedaga.liepaja.edu.lv/projekti/) or any other page on the site.

What bothers me, is that the cookie comes from an upper-level domain (liepaja.edu.lv), which I do not manage. [image] I only manage liedaga.liepaja.edu.lv. I contacted the domain provider and was assured they do not have any Google Analytics on their top-level liepaja.edu.lv domain. Question is, is it Google and Wordpress taking time to clear all these cookies or is the domain provider not knowing or hiding smth? Can cookies be inherited from upper-level doamin? Can someone shine light on this?

I have run caching in WP-Optimize plugin.

Answer (score 3):

Remove/Edit GTM. It deploys the analytics library when there are analytics tags published.

It's easy to test. Block GTM, delete the cookie and reload the page. No cookie set.